# Information records getting printed twice

Tags: powershell

Why below code prints information messages twice? Does information stream has some unique properties?

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$InformationPreference = 'Continue'
$WarningPreference = 'Continue'

$sb = {
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    $InformationPreference = 'Continue'
    $WarningPreference = 'Continue'

    Write-Verbose 'verbose'
    Write-Information 'information'
    Write-Warning 'warning'
}

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
Receive-Job $job
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: verbose
information
information
WARNING: warning
```

I know `$InformationPreference='SilentlyContinue'` by default, and if I change it to default inside or outside script block I will get information records printed once.

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7814

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks, you can add an asnwer if you want